# aprendiendo a usar angular

Tags: angular

como están gente. les escribo por que estoy haciendo un curso en el cual nos están enseñando a usar angular, bueno la cuestión es la siguiente:

Nos dijeron que hiciéramos el front-end de un portfolio que ya realice y pues por supuesto utilice JavaScript para poder utilizar los botones y hacer digamos el funcionamiento básico de la pagina que aparezcan dos ventanas emergentes y demás, pero la cuestión surgió cuando me informaron que ahora lo hecho sin angular tenia que pasarlo a un proyecto de angular.

A lo que pues al principio pude hacerlo sin problemas pero cuando me di cuenta no puedo (y no sé cómo) O si de entrada se puede usar el documento de JavaScript en angular, ya que aquí tenemos typescript entonces esta crudo el front-end de la página.

¿Se puede usar el código de JavaScript o me toca empezar de cero el funcionamiento con typescript?

Intenté enlazando la pagina de javascript creada anterior mente en el angular.json como si fueran los estilos y el js de bootstrap pero me dice el siguiente error:

```
(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at src\app.js:6:1)
```

Pongo en ejemplo el funcionamiento de 1 botón que no me quiere funcionar:

```
var boton = document.getElementById('boton'),
overlay1 = document.getElementById('overlay1'),
formulario = document.getElementById('FormularioInicio'),
salir = document.getElementById('salir1');
boton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        overlay1.classList.add('active');

});
```

puede ser que este haciendo algo mal también jajaja
muchas gracias por la ayuda gente

Comment: La misma documentación de Angular tiene un tutorial que te enseña desde cero, paso a paso: https://angular.io/start Por otro lado, en el código que muestras, solo hay javascript, nada de HTML, tampoco nada de la estructura de archivos que tienes, mucho menos el package.json para saber qué está utilizando tu proyecto, te sugiero esta lectura: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Para desarrollar en Angular y en cualquier framework moderno, se debe adquirir organización de archivos y entender por qué esa organización. Saludos.

Comment: me podnre a leer entonces gracias un saludo

Comment: Adicionalmente, estimados, por favor, eviten poner negativos, Miguel recién ha llegado a SOes, todavía no tiene la medalla del recorrido (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) expliquen dejando un comentario que tiene pinta de querer aprender y crecer. Saludos.

Comment: estudia typescript como parece conoces js no te resultara complicado Tenes muchos cursos creo este es gratis https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/typescript